# Proof of $7^n-2^n$ is divisible by 5 for each integer $n \ge 1$ by mathematical induction.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove the following statement by mathematical induction.
$7^n-2^n$ is divisible by 5 for each integer $n \ge 1$

My attempt: Let the given statement be p(n).
(1) $7-2=5$ is divisible by 5 so p(1) is true.
(2) Suppose as an inductive hypothesis, $7^k-2^k$ is divisible by 5 for each integer $k \ge 1$. That is, p(k) is true for all integer $k \ge 1$

Then we must show that p(k+1) is true:

$7^{k+1}-2^{k+1}$=$7^{k+1}-(7-5)^{k+1}$

I'm stuck on this step. I think I have to separate a multiple of 5 from the above equation, but I can't.

Comment: Your point number (2) is actually taking the the thesis as hypotesis. You should say "suppose by induction hypotesis that $p(k)$ is true for $k \leq n-1$" for a strong induction, or "$p(n-1)$ is true" for a simple induction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$ 7^{k+1}-2^{k+1} = (2+5)7^k - 2\cdot2^k.$$

Or alternatively:

$$ 7^{k+1} - 2^{k+1} = 7\cdot 7^k - (7-5)2^k.$$

Or alternatively yet:

$$ 7^{k+1} - 2^{k+1} = 7\cdot 7^k - 2\cdot 2^k + 7\cdot 2^k - 7\cdot 2^k.$$

There are some more variations of this trick.

Answer (score 4):

Rather use $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}b^0+a^{n-2}b....b^{n-1}$ thus $a-b|(a^n-b^n)$

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find clever tricks, go the slow way. The hypothesis tells you
$$
7^k-2^k=5z
$$
that can be written 
$$
7^k=5z+2^k
$$
Then
$$
7^{k+1}-2^{k+1}=7\cdot7^k-2^{k+1}
=35z+7\cdot2^k-2^{k+1}
$$
and you should be able to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose as an inductive hypothesis, $7^k−2^k$ is divisible by $5$ for each integer $k≥1$.

Then $7^{k+1}-2^{k+1} \vdots 5  \Leftrightarrow  \left ((7^{k+1}-2^{k+1})-(7^k-2^k)  \right )\vdots 5$
$$\left ((7^{k+1}-2^{k+1})-(7^k-2^k)  \right )=7\cdot7^k-2\cdot 2^k-7^k+2^k=$$
$$=6\cdot 7^k-2^k=5\cdot7^k+(7^k-2^k)\vdots 5$$
$5\cdot7^k\vdots 5 -$ obviously

$(7^k-2^k)\vdots 5 -$ an inductive hypothesis